# CMake custom post build step command always executes

Tags: visual-studio, build, cmake

I'm currently trying to compile shaders with CMake, but only when they get changed. I figured it could be done properly but I'm not really experienced in CMake to make this happen.

My folder structure:

```
Root
  + NetcodeClient
  |  + Shaders
  |  |  + CMakeLists.txt
  |  + CMakeLists.txt
  + CMakeLists.txt
```

The top level `Root/CMakeLists.txt` with the project() call inside, I defined the following macro there (I'll only include the vertex shaders, because the rest is just copy pasta):

```
macro(NETCODE_COMPILE_SHADER ownerTarget fileName shaderType entryPoint)
    get_filename_component(strippedFileName ${fileName} NAME_WE)
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${ownerTarget}
                       POST_BUILD
                       DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${fileName}
                       COMMAND ${FXC} /T \"${shaderType}\" /E\"${entryPoint}\" /Od /Zi /Fo \"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders/${strippedFileName}.cso\" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${fileName}
                       BYPRODUCTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders/${strippedFileName}.cso
                       WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    )
endmacro()

macro(NETCODE_COMPILE_VS ownerTarget fileName)
    NETCODE_COMPILE_SHADER(${ownerTarget} ${fileName} "vs_5_0" "main")
endmacro()

[...]

add_subdirectory("NetcodeClient")
```

That I'm using inside the `Root/NetcodeClient/Shaders/CMakeLists.txt` target, looks as follows:

```
set(NETCODE_VS 
    "envMapPass_Vertex.hlsl"
    "gbufferPass_Vertex.hlsl"
    "lightingPass_Vertex.hlsl"
    "skinningPass_Vertex.hlsl"
    "sprite_Vertex.hlsl"
    "ssaoPass_Vertex.hlsl"
)

add_custom_target(NetcodeClientShaders DEPENDS ${NETCODE_VS})

foreach(var ${NETCODE_VS})
    NETCODE_COMPILE_VS(NetcodeClientShaders ${var})
endforeach(var)
```

And then finally in the `Root/NetcodeClient/CMakeLists.txt` I do the following, just to connect the dependencies:

```
add_subdirectory(Shaders)
add_dependencies(NetcodeClient NetcodeClientShaders)
```

The .cso files gets compiled just fine, but it runs every time i press build, which does not take too much time but i'd love to cut this down if possible.

I consulted with the [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_command.html) a lot, and I think I can't add the DEPENDS part when a build-step is being defined. Which by the description is exactly what I'd need here. Could you help me out here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files) to create make rules like GNU make, and collect all the outputs and use [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) to create CMake target.

```
# generate shader output
function(netcode_compile_shader var_binary_path source_path shader_type entry_point)
  get_filename_component(source_filename ${source_path} NAME_WE)
  get_filename_component(source_path "${source_path}" ABSOLUTE)
  set(binary_path "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${source_filename}.cso")
  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${binary_path}
    COMMENT "Generating ${binary_path}..."
    COMMAND ${FXC} /T \"${shader_type}\" /E\"${entry_point}\" /Od /Zi /Fo \"${binary_path}\" \"${source_path}\"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    DEPENDS "${source_path}"
  )
  set(${var_binary_path} "${binary_path}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

# generate vs shader output
macro(netcode_compile_vs var_binary_path source_path)
  netcode_compile_shader(${var_binary_path} ${source_path} "vs_5_0" "main")
endmacro()

# create shader compiling target
set(NETCODE_VS 
  "envMapPass_Vertex.hlsl"
  "gbufferPass_Vertex.hlsl"
  "lightingPass_Vertex.hlsl"
  "skinningPass_Vertex.hlsl"
  "sprite_Vertex.hlsl"
  "ssaoPass_Vertex.hlsl"
)
foreach(vs ${NETCODE_VS})
  netcode_compile_vs(vs_out ${vs})
  list(APPEND NETCODE_VS_OUT ${vs_out})
endforeach()
add_custom_target(NetcodeClientShaders DEPENDS ${NETCODE_VS_OUT})
```